# Removing comma after last name in the last-first biblatex macro

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Biblatex: remove commas between last and first names in bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17583/biblatex-remove-commas-between-last-and-first-names-in-bibliography)

Is there an easy work-around with the last-first biblatex macro so that the comma after the last name in the bibliography entry can be removed?

The goal is to print

> Kruse, JS

as

> Kruse JS

To see some more background to this question, you may refer to my post: [biblatex conditional for printing an extradate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76275/biblatex-conditional-for-printing-an-extradate).

Comment: I wouldn't remove neither the comma nor the periods after the initials. But it's just a personal opinion.