# Omitting fields in Bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, urls, doi

When building my bibliography using the

```
 \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
```

The output looks like

> [88] G. R. Ruetsch and M. R. Maxey. Small-scale features of vorticity
>   and pas- sive scalar fields in homogeneous isotropic turbulence.
>   Physics of Fluids A: Fluid Dynamics, 3(6):1587, 1991. ISSN 08998213.
>   doi: 10.1063/1.857938. URL
>   http://link.aip.org/link/PFADEB/v3/i6/p1587/s1&Agg=doi.

I'd like to omit of some of the fields, such as URL and ISSN.  Is this possible? If so, what do I need to do?

(Note: My BibTex was made using Mendley)

Comment: If you want to omit the `url` and `issn` fields altogether in your references, just do a search and replace in your `bib` file: change `url` into `NOOPurl` and `issn` into `NOOPissn` in the field names and BibTeX will ignore those fields.

Comment: @egreg, If I edit the .bib file, Mendley will just overwrite it when i run it again.  I could make a copy of the .bib file, but then i loose the advantage of having the .bib automatically update when i update in Mendley.

Comment: Do you mean Mendeley? It is evil anyway :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One way to proceed is to create a modified version of the file `plainnat.bst`, in which the functions that format and print fields such as `doi` and `isbn` are reduced to stubs that do nothing:

- Find the file `plainnat.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file and call it, say, `myplainnat.bst`. (Don't edit an original file of the TeX distribution directly.)
- Open `myplainnat.bst` in your favorite text editor, and search for the function called `format.doi`. (In my copy of the file, it starts on line 292.)
- In this function, replace the line

  ```
  { new.block "\doi{" doi * "}" * }
  ```

  with

  ```
  { "" }
  ```

  In short, tell BibTeX to do nothing even if the field `doi` is non-empty. (You could go further and replace the function's entire body with `{ " " }`. However, if you ever choose to undo some of these edits, it may be easier to do so if you leave behind for more than that absolute minimum code snippet.)
- Repeat this procedure, as needed, for the functions `format.url`, `format.issn`, and `format.isbn`.
- Save the file `myplainnat.bst`, either in the directory where your main `.tex` file is located or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter option, you'll probably need to update the filename database of your TeX distribution too.
- Start using the new bibliography style via

  ```
  \bibliographystyle{myplainnat}
  ```

Comment: How do I find the file plainnat.bst in my TeX distribution? (I use Ubunbu)

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi - What does `kpsewhich plainnat.bst` (to be typed from a command line) return?

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about this useful command.

Comment: And your solution works perfectly, thanks again.

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi -- You're welcome!

Comment: OK, this is really the same question with a different title.

Comment: Can't we do it just with code in the *.tex file?

Comment: @Ernesto - If one has to work with the `plainnat` bibliography style (and BibTeX), the answer to your question is "No". If you're free to use the `biblatex` package, you could indeed affect a lot more of the formatting via LaTeX code.

Answer (score 6):

You should use biblatex with this in your preamble (remove `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}`)

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,firstinits=true,citestyle=authoryear,natbib=true,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\renewcommand\nameyeardelim{, }
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{\baselineskip}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
```

Where this gives you the expected removal.

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \clearfield{issn} % Remove issn
  \clearfield{doi} % Remove doi

  \ifentrytype{online}{}{% Remove url except for @online
    \clearfield{url}
  }
}
```

This is based on http://codydunne.blogspot.se/2012/01/suppressing-bibtex-fields-for-specific.html

Answer (score 0):

I have a setup where I have OverLeaf as my LaTeX distribution and it is synced with Zotero. For some reason, Zotero is exporting also a field "note" in my .bib file:

```
@article{osokin_real-time_2018,
title = {Real-time 2D Multi-Person Pose Estimation on {CPU}: Lightweight {OpenPose}},
rights = {Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 International},
url = {https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.12004},
doi = {10.48550/ARXIV.1811.12004},
shorttitle = {Real-time 2D Multi-Person Pose Estimation on {CPU}},
abstract = {In this work we adapt multi-person pose estimation architecture to use it on edge devices. We follow the bottom-up approach from {OpenPose}, the winner of {COCO} 2016 Keypoints Challenge, because of its decent quality and robustness to number of people inside the frame. With proposed network design and optimized post-processing code the full solution runs at 28 frames per second (fps) on Intel\${\textbackslash}unicode\{{xAE}\}\$ {NUC} 6i7KYB mini {PC} and 26 fps on Core\${\textasciicircum}\{{TM}\}\$ i7-6850K {CPU}. The network model has 4.1M parameters and 9 billions floating-point operations ({GFLOPs}) complexity, which is just {\textasciitilde}15\% of the baseline 2-stage {OpenPose} with almost the same quality. The code and model are available as a part of Intel\${\textbackslash}unicode\{{xAE}\}\$ {OpenVINO}\${\textasciicircum}\{{TM}\}\$ Toolkit.},
author = {Osokin, Daniil},
urldate = {2023-02-16},
date = {2018},
note = {Publisher: {arXiv} Version Number: 1 Read\_Status: To Read Read\_Status\_Date: 2023-02-16T14:04:41.638Z},
keywords = {Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition (cs.{CV}), {FOS}: Computer and information sciences}}
```

This made the citations flooded with unnecessary information about the Read Status of the papers (Generated by a Zotero add-on https://github.com/Dominic-DallOsto/zotero-reading-list).

I managed to remove the note by adding the following to the `preamble.tex`

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%
    \clearfield{note}
}
```

Thank you @fredrik-erlandsson your approach works.