# Removing urls froms reference list in natbib

Tags: bibliographies, jabref

I'm using JabRef to manage my references, the [`natbib`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/natbib) package and `jpe` bibliography style.

When I use the `\bibliography{ }` command to generate the reference list, the urls of the documents cited also appear by default, but I dont want them to show.

I'm not sure if its an issue with JabRef, `natbib`, or the bibliography style. Any idea of how to remove them?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! The bibliography style file determines which fields are shown and in which format. See [Omitting fields in Bibliography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/137345/5001) for a recent posting with a very similar objective to yours. What you need to do is edit a copy of the file `jpe.bst` and replace the line `{ "\urlprefix\url{" url * "}" * }` in the function `format.url` with `{ " " }`. Don't edit the original file, but a copy.