# bibliography author-year style, without hyperlinks

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, lyx, natbib

I an confused by the vast BibTeX bibliography styles available in LyX. I can't find the style that fits the requirements of my university.

I currently use the "natbib" citation style, and the "plainnat" bibliography style. The citations in my document are author-year style (which is good), but the bibliographic entires containe full hyperlinks and DOI numbers (which is against my university policy).

I tried to switch from "plainnat" to "plain" or to other styles in the LyX menu, but it appeared to be incompatible with the "author-year" style.

How can I find the style that allows both author-year and removing the links?

Comment: Are you trying to omit the contents of fields such as `url` and `doi` entirely, or "just" the hyperlink aspects of these fields? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico I want to entirely omit the contents of the url and doi fields.   And I don't want to change the .bib file itself because I use the same file in other projects.

Comment: Please see the answer to the recent posting, [Omitting fields in Bibliography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/137345/5001). It also deals with instructing BibTeX to omit various fields such as `doi`, `isbn`, etc. The person who posted the query is, like you, a user of the `plainnat` bibliography style.

Comment: You can also use `biblatex` which makes it easier.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel How do I use biblatex from LyX? I see 3 options there: bibtex, bibtex8, and biber.

Comment: I have no experiences with LyX. However biber is the official backend of biblatex.