# Define bibstyle output hierarchy for doi, url, isbn and issn in BiBTeX

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib, urls, doi

I want to make a hierarchy for printing doi, url, isbn and issn in BiBTeX. Something like this (here "real" means that the bib-field is availably/valid):

```
if "doi" real
   print doi
else
  if "url" real
     print url
  else
    if "isbn" real
       print isbn
    else
      if "issn" real
         print issn
      end
    end
  end
end
```

So "doi" is the most important field to print!

I have looked at [Redundancy in bib file: conditionally suppress url if same as doi?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5660/redundancy-in-bib-file-conditionally-suppress-url-if-same-as-doi/49423?noredirect=1#comment591536_49423) and [Biblatex: Print ISBN only if DOI is not defined](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76534/biblatex-print-isbn-only-if-doi-is-not-defined/76542?noredirect=1#comment591681_76542) to get some idears, but no luck.

MWE: [tex-file](https://db.tt/nCYpgJgI)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{testplainnat}
\citep{test1,test2,test3,test4,test5,test6,test7,test8,test9,test10}
\bibliography{testbib}
\end{document}
```

BIB: [BIB-file](https://db.tt/QKnSwgzx)

```
@Article{test1,
  author =   {Author, A},
  title =    {Title A},
  journal =    {journal},
  year =     2001,
  doi =      {no.},
  note =     {(doi only!)}
}

@Article{test2,
  author =   {Author, B},
  title =    {Title B},
  journal =    {journal},
  year =     2002,
  url =      {no.},
  note =     {(url only!)}
}

@Article{test3,
  author =   {Author, C},
  title =    {Title C},
  journal =    {journal},
  year =     2003,
  isbn =     {no.},
  note =     {(isbn only!)}
}

@Article{test4,
  author =   {Author, D},
  title =    {Title D},
  journal =    {journal},
  year =     2004,
  issn =     {no.},
  note =     {(issn only!)}
}

@Article{test5,
  author =   {Author, E},
  title =    {Title E},
  journal =    {journal},
  year =     2005,
  url =      {no.},
  doi =      {no.},
  note =     {(doi and url)}
}

@Article{test6,
  author =   {Author, F},
  title =    {Title F},
  journal =    {journal},
  year =     2006,
  isbn =     {no.},
  doi =      {no.},
  url =      {no.},
  note =     {(doi, url and isbn)}
}

@Article{test7,
  author =   {Author, G},
  title =    {Title G},
  journal =    {journal},
  year =     2007,
  isbn =     {no.},
  issn =     {no.},
  doi =      {no.},
  url =      {no.},
  note =     {(doi, url, isbn and issn)}
}

@Article{test8,
  author =   {Author, H},
  title =    {Title H},
  journal =    {journal},
  year =     2008,
  isbn =     {no.},
  doi =      {no.},
  note =     {(doi and isbn)}
}

@Article{test9,
  author =   {Author, I},
  title =    {Title I},
  journal =    {journal},
  year =     2009,
  issn =     {no.},
  doi =      {no.},
  note =     {(doi and issn)}
}

@Article{test10,
  author =   {Author, J},
  title =    {Title J},
  journal =    {journal},
  year =     2010,
  isbn =     {no.},
  url =      {no.},
  note =     {(url and isbn)}
}
```

bst:

[test-plainnat-bst-file](https://db.tt/AJLSFZSb)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't know too much about editing BST files, perhaps the declaration of the different publication types is the least error-prone way. At the very end of your `testplainnat.bst`-file you have functions for each doctype like:

```
FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { journal emphasize "journal" output.check
      eid empty$
        { format.vol.num.pages output }
        { format.vol.num.eid output }
      if$
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      eid empty$
        { format.pages output }
        { format.eid output }
      if$
    }
  if$
  format.isbn output
  format.issn output
  format.doi output
  format.url output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}
```

So the interesting part is

```
  format.isbn output
  format.issn output
  format.doi output
  format.url output
  new.block
```

A IF-ELSE-Statement for "use doi or url or issn" looks like:

```
  format.isbn output
  format.doi empty$
  {
    format.url output empty$
    {
      format.issn output empty$
    }
    {
      format.url output
    }
  }
  {
    format.doi output
  }
  if$  
  new.block
```

I think you get the idea from this example. So basically it is

```
<value to test> empty$
{<run this cmd if empty>}
{<run this cmd if not empty>}
```

and a bit of nesting.

Of course you would need to repeat this for every doctype (like `FUNCTION {book}` etc.), but this is easier to handle than changing the format.* functions themselves.

(And this from someone that finds it easy to change bst files but has real issues adapting a biblatex style).

Answer (score 3):

The recently developed [Bibulous project](http://nzhagen.github.io/bibulous/) handles this directly. For article-type entries in a `*.bib` file, an example template definition is the following::

```
article = <au>, \enquote{<title>,} <journal>, <volume>: [<startpage>--<endpage>|<startpage>|<eid>|] (<year>).[ <doi>| <url>| <isbn>| <issn>]
```

At the end of the template is a "option block" which has the effect that if it finds a `doi` field in the database entry, then it will insert it here. If it doesn't find one, then it looks for a `url` field, and inserts it if present. And likewise for `isbn` and `issn`. If none of these fields are present, then the entire `[...]` block is ignored.

This should produce exactly the requested behavior, albeit using Bibulous in place of Biblatex.