# Print ISBN only if DOI is not defined (including in crossref entry!)

Tags: biblatex, conditionals, doi

[A previous question here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/76534/22603) asks whether it is possible for Biblatex to print an entry's ISBN only if it doesn't already contain a DOI.  [The accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/76542/22603) by [Andrew Swann](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/15925/andrew-swann) is to use Biblatex's source remapping features to check whether the `doi` field is non-null, and if so, to clear the `isbn` field so that it is not printed.

The problem with this solution is that it does not work for cross-referenced entries.  For example, say you have a `@proceedings` entry with an `isbn` field, and an `@inproceedings` entry with a  `doi` field as well as a `crossref` field that references the `@proceedings` entry.  In this case, when the `@inproceedings` entry gets printed in the list of references, both the DOI and ISBN are displayed.

Here is a minimal example and the output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
     \map{
        \step[fieldsource=doi,final]
        \step[fieldset=isbn,null]
        }
      }
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@proceedings{book1,
  editor = {Adam Author},
  title = {Book One},
  year = 2020,
  doi = {10.1000/1010},
  note = {DOI only},
}

@proceedings{book2,
  editor = {Betty Bookwriter},
  title = {Book Two},
  year = 2020,
  doi = {10.1000/2020},
  isbn = {123-456-789},
  note = {DOI and ISBN; ISBN should not be displayed},
}

@proceedings{book3,
  editor = {Edward Editor},
  title = {Book Three},
  year = 2020,
  isbn = {123-456-789},
  note = {ISBN only},
}

@inproceedings{article4,
  author =   {Sally Scribe},
  title =    {Article Four},
  doi =      {10:1000/4040},
  crossref = {book3},
  note = {DOI from article, ISBN from crossref should not be displayed},
}

@inproceedings{article5,
  author =   {Walter Writer},
  title =    {Article Five},
  crossref = {book3},
  note = {ISBN from crossref should be displayed},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\nocite{book1,book2,book3,article4,article5}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above LaTeX document, showing that article4 is incorrectly printed with both an ISBN and DOI]

How can Andrew's answer be adapted so that it accounts for `isbn` and `doi` fields in cross-referenced entries?  Or failing this, is there some other solution (short of manually editing the bibliography entries) that will achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sourcemaps are executed fairly early in the `.bib` parsing process way before field aliasing and data inheritance has been applied. This means that your sourcemap simply doesn't know whether an entry will inherit a certain field or not.

It is probably best to suppress the field only on the `biblatex` once all data is available. The conceptually nicest way probably goes through `\AtDataInput`, but it needs a new helper macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\ClearFieldAtDataInput}[1]{%
  \csxappto\blx@bbl@data{%
    \undef\expandafter\noexpand\csname abx@field@#1\endcsname}}
\makeatother

\AtDataInput{%
  \iffieldundef{doi}
    {}
    {\ClearFieldAtDataInput{isbn}}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@proceedings{book1,
  editor = {Adam Author},
  title  = {Book One},
  year   = 2020,
  doi    = {10.1000/1010},
  note   = {DOI only},
}
@proceedings{book2,
  editor = {Betty Bookwriter},
  title  = {Book Two},
  year   = 2020,
  doi    = {10.1000/2020},
  isbn   = {123-456-789},
  note   = {DOI and ISBN; ISBN should not be displayed},
}
@proceedings{book3,
  editor = {Edward Editor},
  title  = {Book Three},
  year   = 2020,
  isbn   = {123-456-789},
  note   = {ISBN only},
}
@inproceedings{article4,
  author   = {Sally Scribe},
  title    = {Article Four},
  doi      = {10:1000/4040},
  crossref = {book3},
  note     = {DOI from article, ISBN from crossref should not be displayed},
}
@inproceedings{article5,
  author   = {Walter Writer},
  title    = {Article Five},
  crossref = {book3},
  note     = {ISBN from crossref should be displayed},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{book1,book2,book3,article4,article5}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: [1] Adam Author, ed. Book One. DOI only. 2020. doi: 10.1000/1010.//[2] Betty Bookwriter, ed. Book Two. DOI and ISBN; ISBN should not be displayed. 2020. doi: 10.1000/2020.//[3] Edward Editor, ed. Book Three. ISBN only. 2020. isbn: 123-456-789.//[4] Sally Scribe. “Article Four”. In: Book Three. Ed. by Edward Editor. DOI from article, ISBN from crossref should not be displayed. 2020. doi: 10:1000/4040.//[5] Walter Writer. “Article Five”. In: Book Three. Ed. by Edward Editor. ISBN from crossref should be displayed. 2020. isbn: 123-456-789.]

---

Alternatively, you can use the standard `\AtEveryBibitem`/`\AtEveryCitekey` hooks

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\newcommand*{\clearisbn}{%
  \iffieldundef{doi}
    {}
    {\clearfield{isbn}}}

\AtEveryBibitem{\clearisbn}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearisbn}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@proceedings{book1,
  editor = {Adam Author},
  title  = {Book One},
  year   = 2020,
  doi    = {10.1000/1010},
  note   = {DOI only},
}
@proceedings{book2,
  editor = {Betty Bookwriter},
  title  = {Book Two},
  year   = 2020,
  doi    = {10.1000/2020},
  isbn   = {123-456-789},
  note   = {DOI and ISBN; ISBN should not be displayed},
}
@proceedings{book3,
  editor = {Edward Editor},
  title  = {Book Three},
  year   = 2020,
  isbn   = {123-456-789},
  note   = {ISBN only},
}
@inproceedings{article4,
  author   = {Sally Scribe},
  title    = {Article Four},
  doi      = {10:1000/4040},
  crossref = {book3},
  note     = {DOI from article, ISBN from crossref should not be displayed},
}
@inproceedings{article5,
  author   = {Walter Writer},
  title    = {Article Five},
  crossref = {book3},
  note     = {ISBN from crossref should be displayed},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{book1,book2,book3,article4,article5}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```