# How to use `\clearfield` in `defbibenvironment` conditional on other field(s)?

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to learn how to customize `biblatex` bibliographies using `\defbibenvironment`; in particular, trying to make a bibliography as compact as possible.

One specific tweak I'm interested in is removing the `eprint` field, but only for those entries that are also published in a journal, that is, those with a non-empty `journaltitle` field.

Is there a way to use `\clearfield` in the fourth argument of `\defbibenvironment` conditional on the value (or existence) of another field?

P.S.: I suggest `\defbinenvironment` only because that has worked for me in the past when I've had multiple bibliographies in a document with different styles. I would be happy with answers not using `\defbinenvironment` as long as they would allow for that.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/424774/print-url-only-if-doi-not-present seems very related.

Comment: Also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/561003/print-isbn-only-if-doi-is-not-defined-including-in-crossref-entry and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76534/biblatex-print-isbn-only-if-doi-is-not-defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test for the existence of fields with `\iffieldundef{<field name>}{<true>}{<false>}`. Do keep in mind that `biblatex` knows three different kinds of fields: plain fields, lists and name lists. Those are tested for with `\iffieldundef`, `\iflistundef` and `\ifnameundef`, respectively. You can find out the "type" of each field in the `biblatex` documentation.

Usually people don't get rid of fields in `\defbibenvironment` (even though that is technically possible), the more common idiom is

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \iffieldundef{journaltitle}
    {}
    {\clearfield{eprint}}%
}
```

Note that `\AtEveryBibitem` applies only to the bibliography. If you also need to affect citations (including `\fullcite`) you need to duplicate the code in `\AtEveryCitekey` as well.

If you want to get rid of a field it is usually more elegant to use a Biber sourcemap instead of `\clearfield`. This clears out the field at the input stage, which means that the field is completely ignored and not just "forgotten about" very late in the game.

For your use case I would make the assumption that an entry has a non-empty `journaltitle` if and only if it is an `@article` so that we can go for

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype = bibtex]{
    \map{
      \pertype{article}
      \step[fieldset=eprint, null]
    }
  }
}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,baez/article,baez/online,wassenberg}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

If you have `@article`s without `journal`/`journaltitle` (I personally think that this is wrong: `@article` is only the right choice if the article is actually published in a journal), then you can also explicitly test for `journal`/`journaltitle` (recall that the former is a legacy alias for the latter, that we need to resolve first)

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype = bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=journal, fieldtarget=journaltitle]
      \step[fieldsource=journaltitle, final]
      \step[fieldset=eprint, null]
    }
  }
}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,baez/article,baez/online,wassenberg}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```