# Multiple doi, url, and eprint entries in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, urls, doi

I'm in the process of writing a `biblatex` style file to support the on-line journal [Theory of Computing](http://www.theoryofcomputing.org/). The journal has been using BibTeX for years, and I am looking forward to the flexibility `biblatex` offers.

**The difficulty**: Our bibliographic entries typically need to refer to *multiple* dois, urls, or eprint entries. (Why? We often link to "preliminary" versions of an article, typically a conference article or an [arXiv](http://arxiv.org) preprint.) My first question is a bit of a meta-question: what's the nicest approach?

Two approaches come to mind; I don't have enough experience with `biblatex` to decide which one to pursue.

### Approach 1

*Arrange for biblatex to "natively" handle multiple dois, urls, eprints, etc.* Specifically, it would be nice to permit a record to have several fields of the form

```
doi = {first-doi},
doi = {second-doi},
...
```

and

```
url = {first-url},
url = {second-url},
...
```

The idea would be that each of these produces its own output: DOI: *first-doi*, DOI: *second-doi*, etc. Is this within easy reach?

Of course, the idea of processing multiple eprint entries seems problematic, since an `eprint` field is typically coupled with other "helper" fields such as `eprinttype`. (Incidentally, supporting two eprint fields seems like something that one might wish to do in many other natural circumstances, such as where a paper has both a MathSciNet entry *and* a DOI).

### Approach 2

Given the problem with even parsing multiple eprint fields, another possibility would be to add a number of new fields:

- `prelim-doi`
- `prelim-eprint`
- `prelim-url`
- `prelim-manuscript`

These are to be printed right after the regular `doi`, `eprint`, and `url` entries (for a journal, say). Specifically, I would like output along the lines of:

```
Preliminary versions: DOI: ..., eprint: ..., URL: ..., Manuscript: ... .
```

Handling of DOI, eprint, and URL should be just like the corresponding "regular" fields (in particular, I would like `prelim-eprint` to inherit the same eprint handlers that exist for `eprint`). Manuscript should be handled just like `eprint` as well (again with the same handlers). (If you are wondering why we need both `prelim-eprint` and `prelim-manuscript`, this is because we often need to cite both a preliminary conference version, using eprint, and also a preliminary arXiv version.)

### My first attempt (for approach 2)

To get my feet wet, I tried the following (in a `.bbx` file):

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{prelim-doi}{%
  \mkbibacro{DOI}\addcolon\space
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{http://dx.doi.org/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}

\newbibmacro*{prelim-doi+eprint+manuscript+url}{%
  \iftoggle{bbx:doi}
  {\printfield{prelim-doi}}
  {}}

\renewbibmacro*{doi+eprint+url}{%
  \iftoggle{bbx:doi}
  {\printfield{doi}}
  {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
  {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
  {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:url}
  {\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}
  {}%
  \iftoggle{bbx:preliminary}
  {\usebibmacro{prelim-doi+eprint+manuscript+url}}
  {}}
```

This uses a toggle called `bbx:preliminary` and was just intended to handle printing preliminary dois (to get started). However, it never seems to print anything (even for a record with a `prelim-doi` field). Is there something fancy I need to do to tell `biblatex` about the new fields? (Incidentally, this little `.bbx` file is essentially just loaded over Marco Daniel's trad-plain style (see [How to emulate the traditional BibTeX styles (plain, abbrv, unsrt, alpha) as closely as possible with biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58152/how-to-emulate-the-traditional-bibtex-styles-plain-abbrv-unsrt-alpha-as-clo)), since our traditional bibliography style is not far from BibTeX's `plain` style.)

Comment: The problem is that BibLaTeX does not know the field `prelim-doi`, and the it ignores it. See the solution by PLK to the question http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/76275/16895 for how to modify the data model.  You have to define a new entry type (in your case `prelim-doi`). Also, for approach 1 you can change the data model for the field and define them as lists, and parse them as lists.

Comment: Thanks very much for the pointer: I'll look into modifying the data model as you suggest. As the "first approach" would be much slicker, I am interested in your proposal to parse these fields as lists. For entries such as doi and url, that seems--in principle--straightforward. Parsing eprint entries as lists, however, seems trickier because of the helper fields.

Comment: For `eprint` the parsing could be done by checking whether the value is a full `URL` (check whether it starts with `http://` or `ftp://` or similar,  in that case you output the current value of `eprint`) otherwise you use `eprintype` to add the appropriate prefix.

Comment: I'm a little confused: Do you mean that you can somehow embed the `eprinttype` information directly in the `eprint` string? I couldn't find a mention of this in the biblatex manual--could you explain how this convention works?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you use biber, this might be best handled with the related entries feature supported by biblatex 2.0+.

The preamble below defines a new type of related entry: `prelim`. This key specifies the localization string, formatting directive and bibliography macro used to set the entries given in the `related` field.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\renewcommand*{\relatedpunct}{\addcolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\relateddelim}{\addcomma\space}

\newbibmacro*{related:prelim}[1]{%
  \renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}%
  \entrydata{#1}{\usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}}}

\NewBibliographyString{prelim,prelims}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{american}{%
  prelim = {Preliminary version},
  prelims = {Preliminary versions}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{v008a021,
  author = {Roy Kasher and Julia Kempe},
  title = {Two-Source Extractors Secure Against Quantum Adversaries},
  year = {2012},
  pages = {461-486},
  doi = {10.4086/toc.2012.v008a021},
  journal = {Theory of Computing},
  volume = {8},
  number = {1},
  related = {kasher/arxiv,kasher/approx},
  relatedtype = {prelim}}
@online{kasher/arxiv,
  author = {Kasher, Roy and Kempe, Julia},
  title = {Two-Source Extractors Secure Against Quantum Adversaries},
  eprinttype = {arxiv},
  eprintclass = {quant-ph},
  eprint = {1005.0512},
  month = may,
  year = {2010}}
@inproceedings{kasher/approx,
  author = {Kasher, Roy and Kempe, Julia},
  title = {Two-source extractors secure against quantum adversaries},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of the 13th international conference on Approximation,
    and the 14th International conference on Randomization, and combinatorial
    optimization: algorithms and techniques},
  series = {APPROX/RANDOM'10},
  year = {2010},
  venue = {Barcelona, Spain},
  pages = {656--669},
  url = {http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1886521.1886572},
  publisher = {Springer-Verlag},
  location = {Berlin, Heidelberg}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{v008a021}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here biber accesses data for every entry indicated in the `related` field. Each related entry is assigned a hash key and is marked `dataonly`. This avoids extraneous entries in the bibliography. It also allows you to cite related works directly and create "circular" relationships between entries.

Since you probably won't be citing preliminary works you could get by without biber, using some additional code to access related entry data and a few more LaTeX/BibTeX runs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,defernumbers]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{related}

\newrobustcmd*{\getrelated}[1]{%
  \nocite{#1}\addtocategory{related}{#1}}

\AtDataInput{%
  \iffieldundef{usera}{}{\forcsvfield{\getrelated}{usera}}}

\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \iffieldundef{usera}{}{%
    \edef\bbxusera{\thefield{usera}}%
    \edef\bbxuserb{\thefield{userb}}%
    \restorefield{related}{\bbxusera}%
    \restorefield{relatedtype}{\bbxuserb}}}

\renewcommand*{\relatedpunct}{\addcolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\relateddelim}{\addcomma\space}

\newbibmacro*{related:prelim}[1]{%
  \renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}%
  \entrydata{#1}{\usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}}}

\NewBibliographyString{prelim,prelims}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{american}{%
  prelim = {Preliminary version},
  prelims = {Preliminary versions}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{v008a021,
  author = {Roy Kasher and Julia Kempe},
  title = {Two-Source Extractors Secure Against Quantum Adversaries},
  year = {2012},
  pages = {461-486},
  doi = {10.4086/toc.2012.v008a021},
  journal = {Theory of Computing},
  volume = {8},
  number = {1},
  usera = {kasher/arxiv,kasher/approx},
  userb = {prelim}}
@online{kasher/arxiv,
  author = {Kasher, Roy and Kempe, Julia},
  title = {Two-Source Extractors Secure Against Quantum Adversaries},
  eprinttype = {arxiv},
  eprintclass = {quant-ph},
  eprint = {1005.0512},
  month = may,
  year = {2010}}
@inproceedings{kasher/approx,
  author = {Kasher, Roy and Kempe, Julia},
  title = {Two-source extractors secure against quantum adversaries},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of the 13th international conference on Approximation,
    and the 14th International conference on Randomization, and combinatorial
    optimization: algorithms and techniques},
  series = {APPROX/RANDOM'10},
  year = {2010},
  venue = {Barcelona, Spain},
  pages = {656--669},
  url = {http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1886521.1886572},
  publisher = {Springer-Verlag},
  address = {Berlin, Heidelberg}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{v008a021}
\printbibliography[notcategory=related]
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is extremely impressive--you implemented my favorite version of the solution with about 9 lines of code! We don't currently use biber; this seems like a good reason to migrate.

Comment: Biber accesses data for related entries and marks them "data only" unless they are cited directly. You could probably do this manually with BibTeX, but it's relatively messy and would require multiple BibTeX/LaTeX runs. I should find some time to incorporate automatic use of plural strings. I'll update this solution when I get around to it.

Comment: An update to handle the singular/plural case would be terrific!

Comment: I am a little confused about what features of `biber` are relevant here (or, equivalently, what will go wrong if I use `bibtex` as the back end); could you explain? Additionally, if it isn't too much trouble, I would be grateful if you could indicate the streamlined version using the built-in handling of plural strings.

Comment: @acr I've updated the solution to address use of BibTeX and plural strings.

Comment: @acr No problem. Thanks to you as well - I never considered plural strings in making the style changes for related entries.

Comment: It seems the `bibtex` variant no longer works with recent versions of the biblatex package - the related entries are not shown (just tested on 3.12). The `biber` variant does work.