# Multiple papers in one BibTeX entry

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I'm quite surprised by the fact that this question hasn't appeared before (or I just couldn't find one), because the situation looks very common to me.

Namely, I have to cite an article, but since it is written in Russian, I also want to supply a link to the English translation on arXiv. Of course, it is possible to add a comment to the end of the entry, like "~paper info~ (in Russian, see English translation at arXiv:~number~)", but this looks not very good to me.

Is it possible to place two article in one BibTeX entry? If not, what is the suitable bibliography package to do it?

Comment: If you can use BibLaTeX a possible solution would be to use `related` (see the answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/77653/16895)

Comment: Using `bibtex`'s cross referencing features and the package [mciteplus](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mciteplus) may help, if `biblatex` is not an option.

Comment: If you use crossref in bibtex (think of it like inheritance in OOP programming) you can have a standard set of base features, inherited by variants (ie the one paper in multiple languages)

Comment: I voted for closing because here is no response of the Andrei.