# German APA reference: origyear field is incomplete (needs reprinttitle)

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I use LuaTeX, BibLaTeX and biber with APA bibliography style. The German version has the `origyear` field wrong.

The original english APA version wants it like this:

> **Author** (**Year**). **Title**. **Location**: **Publisher**. (Original
>   work published **original year**)

The German version is the same, just "Original work published is replaced by "Original erschienen" which is fine. But according to the adjusted version by the German DGP the rest should look like this:

> **Author** (**Year**). **Title**. **Location**: **Publisher**. (Original erschienen
>   **original year**: **original title**)

But we can't even use the `origtitle` field and just move it around. Because the `origtitle` field is a field for the title when the `title` field is already used for a self-made translation of the title. Imagine the following case:

> Smith, A. (1990). L'amour [Die Liebe]. Paris: Alfons. (Original
>   erschienen 1988: Love).

So we have a French translation of an originally English book and we give a German translation so everybody understands it. `title` field is for our translation "Die Liebe", `origtitle` is for the title of the translated work "L'amour" so we need another field for the title of the original work "Love". This can't be appended to `origyear` because we need `origyear` seperately when we cite it like this: Smith (1988/1990).

We would need something like a `origwork` field which is appended to the `origyear` and also very flexible because if the original work has slightly different authors (what the heck??) DGP turns it into:

> Zimbardo, P. G. & Gerrig, R. J. (2004). ... (Original erschienen 2002 als Gerrig, R. J. & Zimbardo, P. G., Psychology and life)

And DGP is also a little inconsistent. There can be found:

> (Original erschienen 1988: Love)

and

> (Original erschienen 1988, Love)

Anyway, does anybody know how to implement this in the german-apa.lbx? I wouldn't even know where to start ...

**EDIT:**

Thanks alot Guido, that's almost what I need.

It's a little bit messed up though. This shifts everything around. There is no need for that. `title`, `subtitle` and `origtitle` should stay in place. We just need an additional field. We can't use `titleaddon` for that because this is put in square brackets (we couldn't use title/subtitle either because it's in italics but shouldn't be if used as title of an original work). We would just need another field `origwork`.

Here is what I got so far:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[american,english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,babel=other]{biblatex}
\usepackage[autopunct=true,autostyle=true,german=guillemets,english=american]{csquotes}
\bibliography{test.bib}        
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}

\begin{filecontents}{biblatex-dm.cfg}
    \DeclareDatamodelFields[type=list, datatype=name,skipout=false]{origauthor}
    \DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{origauthor}
    \DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=literal,skipout=false]{origwork}
    \DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{origwork} 
    \end{filecontents}

    \DeclareFieldFormat{origyear}{%
     \mkbibparens{\bibcpstring{origyear}~\thefield{origyear}%
     \ifnameundef{origauthor}
       {}
       {\addspace als \printnames[author]{origauthor}}%
     \iffieldundef{origwork}
       {}%
       {\ifnameundef{origauthor}
         {\setunit{\addcolon\addspace}}
         {\setunit{\addcomma\addspace}}%
         \printfield{origwork}}}%
     }

    \renewbibmacro*{origyear}{%
      \ifthenelse{
          \NOT\iffieldsequal{labelyear}{origdateyear}
        \OR
          \NOT\iffieldsequal{title}{origwork}
        \OR
          \NOT\ifnamesequal{author}{origauthor}
        }
        {\printfield{origyear}}
        {}%
    }

\begin{document}
\textcite{testentry}
\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

test.bib:

```
@BOOK{testentry,
  author = {Adam Smith},
  title = {Die Liebe},
  origtitle = {L'amour},
  location = {Paris},
  publisher = {Alfons},
  date = {1994},
  origdate = {1988},
  origauthor = {Adam Smith-Degen},
  origwork = {Love},
  hyphenation = {ngerman},
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

I see now, you have turned everything upside down so it fits its semantic purpose. And biblatex-apa is a little inconsistent using `title` for title but using `origtitle` for title if there is a selfmade translation which is filled in as `title`. Anyway this is what everyone is using right now. We can just add up missing pieces using unused fields. Here is my try with `reprinttitle`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[american,english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,babel=other]{biblatex}
\usepackage[autopunct=true,autostyle=true,german=guillemets,english=american]{csquotes}
\bibliography{test.bib}        
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}

\DeclareFieldFormat{origyear}{%
 \mkbibparens{\bibcpstring{origyear}~\thefield{origyear}%
 \ifnameundef{origauthor}
   {}
   {\addspace als \printnames[author]{origauthor}}%
 \iffieldundef{reprinttitle}
   {}%
   {\ifnameundef{origauthor}
     {\setunit{\addcolon\addspace}}
     {\setunit{\addcomma\addspace}}%
     \printfield{reprinttitle}}}%
 }

\renewbibmacro*{origyear}{%
  \ifthenelse{
      \NOT\iffieldsequal{labelyear}{origdateyear}
    \OR
      \NOT\iffieldsequal{title}{reprinttitle}
    \OR
      \NOT\ifnamesequal{author}{origauthor}
    }
    {\printfield{origyear}}
    {}%
}

\begin{document}
\textcite{testentry}
\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

test.bib:

```
@BOOK{testentry,
  author = {Adam Smith},
  title = {Die Liebe},
  subtitle = {in all ihren Formen},
  origtitle = {L'amour},
  location = {Paris},
  publisher = {Alfons},
  date = {1994},
  origdate = {1988},
  origauthor = {Adam Smith},
  titleaddon = {Special issue},
  reprinttitle = {Love},
  hyphenation = {ngerman},
}
```

Now it looks like:

> Smith, A. (1994). *L'amour* [Die Liebe: in all ihren Formen] [Special
>   issue]. Paris: Alfons. (Original erschienen 1988 als Smith, A., Love).

**Things to do:** "als" would also need to be a key that is "als" in a German bibliography and "as" in an English bibliography. The author's name is Surname, F. but should be F. Surname. I would be glad if you could elaborate on that.

Comment: Related: my question [biblatex conditional for printing an extradate](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76275/biblatex-conditional-for-printing-an-extradate) See answer by PLK.

Comment: I don't see the reason why `titleaddon` is not appropriate.  According to the specs you gave, what you called `origintitle` (Die Liebe) was enclosed in brackets. Also the schema you are using is confusing. If you use the `.bib` with another style, you will get wrong information. In addition it is very easy to change how `titleaddon` is rendered. i.e., `\DeclareFieldFormat{titleaddon}{\MakeSentenceCase*{#1}}`.

Comment: `titleaddon` can't be used because it's already in use in apa style for declaring additional information concerning the medium (special issue, brochure, CD, monograph, editorial, abstract). E.g. it could be filled with "Special issue" in case we are dealing with a French translation of an English journal article published in a special issue of a French journal. I've seen this rarely but it exists.

Comment: Ok, for `titleaddon` though I still think that what you want is part of such information (and as far as I can see, the original spa style handles original only for books).  Part of my problem is, if I have understood properly your narrative, that in your `.bib`, `title` is not the _title_ but the translation of it.  I would use `author`, `title` for the main entry, `origauthor`, `origtitle` and introduce a new field for the extra information, e.g., `extratitleinfo`. The next issue is how to render it and its position.

Comment: Well, `title` is not just used for the translation of the title in my .bib but in anyone's .bib if using biblatex-apa. - But only if there is a need for a selfmade translation. In this case title moves from the `title` field to the `origtitle` field. See e.g. in biblatex-apa-test.pdf 7.01:4 and corresponding entry in file biblatex-apa-test-references.bib which are part of the doc. So `origtitle` and `titleaddon` are both already in use by apa style - I would be fine with a new field `extratitleinfo` but also with a reused field `reprinttitle` which isn't used yet by that style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the original question, the modification required is:

```
\renewbibmacro*{title}{%
  \ifthenelse{\iffieldundef{title}\AND\iffieldundef{subtitle}}
    {}
    {\printtext[title]{%
        \printfield[apacase]{title}%
        \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
        \printfield[apacase]{subtitle}}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printfield{titleaddon}%
     \iffieldequalstr{entrytype}{book}%
       {\setunit{\addspace}\usebibmacro{bookaddinfo}}%
       {}%
     \ifthenelse{%
       \ifnameundef{author}\AND%
       \(\ifnameundef{editor}\AND\NOT\boolean{bbx:editorinauthpos}\)\AND%
       \ifnameundef{producer}\AND%
       \ifnameundef{director}\AND%
       \ifnameundef{writer}}
        {\newunit\newblock
         \usebibmacro{labelyear+extrayear}}
        {}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{origyear}{%
 \mkbibparenss{\bibcpstring{origyear}~\thefield{origyear}%
 \iffieldundef{origtitle}
   {}%
   {\addcolon\addspace\printfield{origtitle}}}%
 }

\newbibmacro*{origyear}{%
  \ifthenelse{
      \NOT\iffieldundef{labelyear}
      \AND\NOT\iffieldsequal{labelyear}{origyear}
    \OR
      \NOT\iffieldsequal{title}{origtitle}}
    {\printfield{origyear}}
    {}%
}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
   origyear = {Original erschienen}
}
```

This can be inserted in the preamble of your document.

For the extended version one has either to introduce new fields (this can be done,by modifying the data model, or by using the BibLaTeX facilities for `related`).

**EDIT 1 and EDIT 2**
To accommodate the case where the author of the original publication is different the first step is to modify the data model, this can be done with:

```
\begin{filecontents}{biblatex-dm.cfg}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=list, datatype=name,skipout=false]{origauthor}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{origauthor}  
\end{filecontents}
```

This generates a file called `biblatex-dm.cfg` in the current directory with the  instruction about how to extend BibLaTeX data model.

Notice that BibLaTeX provides a `titleaddon` field and this could be used to the extra information for the title ("Die Liebe" in the OP).

Eventually, one could add a field `titletranslation` for the selfmade translation, i.e., one can include the following two lines in the datamodel file.

```
\DeclareDatamodelField[type=field, datatype=literal,skipout=false]{titletranslation}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{titletranslation}
```

Another possibility is to use an "unused" field, for example, `reprinttitle`. In what follow I'm going to use this option.

The next step is to modify the appropriate `bibmacro`s.  In this case, `title` and `origyear` for the formatting of the title (and related information about the original publication)

```
\renewbibmacro*{title}{%
  \ifthenelse{\iffieldundef{title}\AND\iffieldundef{subtitle}}
    {}
    {\printtext[title]{%
        \printfield[apacase]{title}%
        \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
        \printfield[apacase]{subtitle}}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printfield{titleaddon}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printfield{reprinttitle}%
     \iffieldequalstr{entrytype}{book}%
       {\setunit{\addspace}\usebibmacro{bookaddinfo}}%
       {}%
     \ifthenelse{%
       \ifnameundef{author}\AND%
       \(\ifnameundef{editor}\AND\NOT\boolean{bbx:editorinauthpos}\)\AND%
       \ifnameundef{producer}\AND%
       \ifnameundef{director}\AND%
       \ifnameundef{writer}}
        {\newunit\newblock
         \usebibmacro{labelyear+extrayear}}
        {}}}
```

For `originyear` the first thing to do is to define the format. To this we check that `originauthor` is defined, and we set the punctuation accordingly:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{origyear}{%
 \mkbibparens{\bibcpstring{origyear}~\thefield{origyear}%
 \ifnameundef{origauthor}
   {}
   {\addspace\bibstring{as}\addspace\printnames[FirstLast]{origauthor}}%
 \iffieldundef{origtitle}
   {}%
   {\ifnameundef{origauthor}
     {\setunit{\addcolon\addspace}}
     {\setunit{\addcomma\addspace}}%
     \printfield{origtitle}}}%
 }
```

Then we have to consider the cases when we have to output the information about the original publication (here the condition is that either the year, or the title, or the author(s) is different).

```
\renewbibmacro*{origyear}{%
  \ifthenelse{
      \NOT\iffieldsequal{labelyear}{origdateyear}
    \OR
      \NOT\iffieldsequal{title}{origtitle}
    \OR
      \NOT\ifnamesequal{author}{origauthor}
    }
    {\printfield{origyear}}
    {}%
}
```

*Caveat* A problem with the above solution is that not all bib entry types include instructions to format the information about the original publication using the above method. A more robust technique would be to use the facilities provided by BibLaTeX to handle related publications.

The last step is to use the appropriate value for the localisation strings `origyear` and `as`.

```
\NewBibliographyString{origyear,as}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
   origyear = {Original erschienen},
   as = {als}
} 

\DefineBibliographyStrings{american}{%
   as = {as} 
}
```

Finally, to change the rendering of names, we have to modify the formatting instructions for `apaauthor`

```
\DeclareNameFormat{FirstLast}{%
 \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}=\maxprtauth\AND\value{listcount}<\value{listtotal}}
    {\addcomma\addspace\ldots}
    {\ifthenelse{\value{listcount}>\maxprtauth\AND\value{listcount}<\value{listtotal}}
      {}
      {\iffirstinits
        {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}}
        {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}}}
  \ifmorenames{\andothersdelim\bibstring{andothers}}{}}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your reply.

I'm sorry, I made a mistake. There is a `year` field but if there are year and original year this changes to `date` and `origdate`. I replaced `origyear` with `origdate` in your code but this won't work.

I'm also still interested in a solution with a new field.

Comment: I looked into the biblatex manual and we could use `reprinttitle`. It's actually meant to be used for the _new_ title of a reprint (or let's say a translation) but we could also use it for the title of the original work the translation is based on. I adjusted the example in my question accordingly. Things still to do are:  A key that is "als" in a German bibliography and "as" in an English bibliography. The author's name is Surname, F. but should be F. Surname.

Comment: Thanks alot, the 2nd edit is almost it. But the name order is still wrong. APA (and DGP) wants order of names to look like this depending on the position: `Surname, F. (2000). Title. In F. Surname, Title (pp. 1-4). Location: Publisher. (Originally published 1999 as F. Surname, Title)` - Now it looks like this: `F. Surname (2000). ... (Originally published 1999 as Surname, F., Title)` - So we need only a modification of the order of origauthor names.

Comment: @PsychicBirdy changed `[author]` to `[apaauthor]` in `\printname[apaauthor]{origauthor}`.

Comment: Now its: `F. Surname (2000). ... (Originally published 1999 as F. Surname, Title)` - But it should be: `Surname, F. (2000). ... (Originally published 1999 as F. Surname, Title)`

Comment: @PsychicBirdy changed again. `\printname[FirstLast]{origauthor}` and changed the name of the formating instruction `\DeclareNameFormat{FirstLast}`, it was `apaauthor`.

Comment: Almost ... Now concerning INBOOK entries it's: `Surname, F. (2000). Title. In Surname, F., Title (pp. 1-4). Location: Publisher. (Originally published 1999 as F. Surname, Title)` while it's supposed to be: `Surname, F. (2000). Title. In F. Surname, Title (pp. 1-4). Location: Publisher. (Originally published 1999 as F. Surname, Title)`

Comment: @PsychicBirdy removed `\DeclareNameAlias{apanames}{apaauthor}`. It  should fix the issue.

Comment: Yes indeed, now it's perfect. So thanks alot! :)