# Modify (german) APA Bibliography to include origlocation and origpublisher with origyear

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, apa-style

this is my first question here, so please be kind if I make stupid mistakes. I am using overleaf (I also have TexWorks installed but prefer overleaf to sync between devices (and because the visual editor is quite nice)), so I can't really see every file.

I use the apa-syle as a base, but want to modify it (I don't need to comply with the guidelines but like apa most). My problem is that apa doesn't include the fields `origlocation` and `origpublisher`. I want to include them in the parenthesis of `origdate` at the end of the bibliography entry which reads:

> (Original erschienen 1890)

What I want is one of these (I don't care which format of `origpublisher` is displayed, I'll take whatever works):

> (Original erschienen 1890, Hamburg, Hrsg. von F. Engels)

> (Original erschienen 1890, Hamburg, Friedrich Engels (Hrsg.))

> (Original erschienen 1890, Hamburg, Engels, F. (Hrsg.))

In my MWE, I included 4 bib-entries: The first (Weber) only has `origdate`, so is doing fine. The second (Marx) is what I described above. The third (Schumpeter) has `origdate` and `origpublisher` and should display as:

> (Original erschienen 1942, Hrsg. von E. Salin)

The fourth (Piketty) additionally has `origtitle`, which would be nice to include into the parenthesis. [There is already an answered question regarding this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78247/german-apa-reference-origyear-field-is-incomplete-needs-reprinttitle), but I don't really understand it, wasn't able to implement it and its also not that important for me now. Same goes for including `series` and `number` in the apa-style, [which was answered here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324509/change-series-number-entries-in-bibliography-with-biblatex).

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 

\usepackage[backend=biber,
                           %citestyle=authoryear-icomp,
                           %bibstyle=apa,
                           style=apa,
                           ]{biblatex} % https://mediatum.ub.tum.de/doc/1315979/1315979.pdf https://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/info/translations/biblatex/de/biblatex-de-Benutzerhandbuch.pdf
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{
    uniquelist=false,   
%    origdate=apalong, %https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/blob/master/tex/latex/biblatex-apa/bbx/apa.bbx
}

\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addspace} % remove comma in (Beadle and Tautum, 1941) This applies to citation only https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/452228/modifying-bibliography-with-biblatex-biber-apa-style-locationpublisherdoi

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@InCollection{Weber1972,
  author    = {Weber, Max},
  date      = {1972},
  title     = {Wirtschaft und Gesellschaft: Grundriß der verstehenden Soziologie},
  edition   = {5., rev. Aufl.},
  isbn      = {3165336318},
  language  = {ger},
  location  = {Tübingen},
  publisher = {Mohr},
  origdate  = {1922},
  type      = {Band},
}

@InCollection{Marx1962,
  author         = {Marx, Karl},
  booktitle      = {Das Kapital},
  date           = {1962},
  title          = {Der Produktionsprozeß des Kapitals},
  booksubtitle   = {Kritik der politischen Ökonomie},
  edition        = {Nach der 4. Aufl.},
  location       = {Berlin},
  publisher      = {Dietz},
  volume         = {1},
  origdate       = {1890},
  origlocation   = {Hamburg},
  origpublisher  = {Engels, Friedrich},
}

@Book{Schumpeter1987,
  author         = {Schumpeter, Joseph A.},
  date           = {1987},
  title          = {Kapitalismus, Sozialismus und Demokratie},
  edition        = {6},
  editor         = {Seifert, Eberhard K.},
  isbn           = {3772012981},
  language       = {ger},
  location       = {Tübingen},
  number         = {172},
  pagetotal      = {542},
  publisher      = {Francke},
  series         = {Uni-Taschenbücher},
  address        = {Tübingen},
  origpublisher  = {Salin, Edgar},
  origdate       = {1942},
}

@Book{Piketty2016,
  author       = {Piketty, Thomas},
  date         = {2016},
  title        = {Das Kapital im 21. Jahrhundert},
  edition      = {1. Aufl. als Paperback},
  location     = {München},
  number       = {6236},
  origlanguage = {french},
  publisher    = {C.H.Beck},
  series       = {C.H. Beck Paperback},
  translator   = {Utz, Ilse and Lorenzer, Stefan},
  origdate     = {2013},
  origtitle    = {Le Capital au XXIe Si{\'e}cle},
  ppn_gvk      = {1830858505},
}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

Lorem \parencite[190]{Marx1962}. Ipsum \parencite[30]{Weber1972}. Dolor \parencite[60]{Piketty2016}. Sit amet \parencite[391]{Schumpeter1987}.


\section{Bibliography}

\printbibliography[heading=none]

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Output of MWE]

So thanks for any help with that.

Comment: Herausgeber is `editor` and not `publisher`. So in this case you'd be looking for "`origeditor`" (which doesn't exist) instead of `origpublisher`. `editor` is a name list, whereas `publisher` is just a normal list field without name parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partial answer to get you started.

The definition for printing `origyear` in `apa.bbx` is given as a `\newbibmacro` and not as a `\DeclareFieldFormat`. If you want to use that definition as a quick (but not necessarily semantically correct) way to add also the location and publisher then you can renew that macro.

```
\renewbibmacro*{origyear}{%
  \printtext[parens]{%
       \bibcpstring{origyear}
       \setunit{\addnbspace}%
       \printorigdate%
     \iflistundef{origlocation}%
       {}%
       {\addcomma\addspace \printlist{origlocation}}%
     \iflistundef{origpublisher}%
       {}%
       {\addcomma\addspace Hrsg. von \printlist{origpublisher}}%
     }%
}
```

Result:

[image]

You can see in the macro that `origlocation` and `origpublisher` are of type `list`. This comes from the `.bbl` file that Biber generates:

```
\entry{Marx1962}{inbook}{}
      \name{author}{1}{}{%
        {{un=0,uniquepart=base,hash=af80d32a7d375e934f94bdfb27bf2999}{%
           family={Marx},
           familyi={M\bibinitperiod},
           given={Karl},
           giveni={K\bibinitperiod},
           givenun=0}}%
      }
      \list{location}{1}{%
        {Berlin}%
      }
      \list{origlocation}{1}{%
        {Hamburg}%
      }
      \list{origpublisher}{1}{%
        {Engels, Friedrich}%
      }
      \list{publisher}{1}{%
        {Dietz}%
      }
      % [...some entries removed...]
      \field{booksubtitle}{Kritik der politischen Ökonomie}
      \field{booktitle}{Das Kapital}
      \field{edition}{Nach der 4. Aufl.}
      \field{origyear}{1890}
      \field{title}{Der Produktionsprozeß des Kapitals}
```

List entries are printed as is, without applying name formatting, so this results in *Hrsg. von Engels, Friedrich* instead of *Hrsg. von F. Engels* what you wanted.

It would therefore be better if Biber would know that `origpublisher` is a person name, then it could extract and format the first name, last name, initials, like for Marx in the `.bbl` fragment above. This requires changes to the data model, as was also done in the linked post, by writing a custom `biblatex-dm.cfg`. In the mean time of course you can change the `.bib` file to perform the formatting of the publisher name manually.

Comment: That worked quite good, but I had to add ` \ifboolexpr{not test {\iffieldundef{origyear}} not test {\iffieldundef{labelyear}} and not test {\iffieldsequal{labelyear}{origyear}}}` from `apa.bbx` before `printtext[parens]...` to clear the field for entries without `origyear`.