# CSE citation style

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I am trying to submit an article in [Plant Ecology and Diversity journal](http://www.tandfonline.com/loi/tped20#.VoFbfh5kaJM). They accept LaTeX format. [Here](http://www.tandfonline.com/action/authorSubmission?journalCode=tped20&page=instructions#.VoFk8B5kaJM) is the Author's Guidelines. However, they use CSE citation style. They didn't provide any LaTeX template or `.bst` file for citation. I searched a lot in the web, but it seems that only this style is missing. I know I could make the custom `.bst` file with `makebst`, but I never tried that.

Any help will be appreciated.

Note: I found couple of related posts about it in this forum However, those discussions didn't reach any solution to this problem. Here are the links of those posts.

1. [Is there a current bibtex file for CSE citation style?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196240/is-there-a-current-bibtex-file-for-cse-citation-style)
2. [Biblatex Style or Package for Council of Science Editors Citation Format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64260/biblatex-style-or-package-for-council-of-science-editors-citation-format)

Comment: can you link to the author guidelines where LaTeX is mentioned?

Comment: I added Author's Guideline link.

Comment: Did you try to run the `makebst` utility to create a bibliography style file that implements the CSE guidelines?

Comment: Perhaps I will do that. But I was hoping that someone might have already created that style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

inally I run the `makebst` utility and manage to get a `.bst` file for [CSE style](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ukuzb125h3w8vub/CSE.bst?dl=0). It looks good. I tested it for journal article, book and book-section, Ph.D. and Master's thesis (which I need at this moment). 
Note: I used the following code in the preamble

```
\usepackage[round,sort&compress]{natbib}
\setcitestyle{aysep={}}
```

Answer (score 4):

Thank you, Harun for the kind sharing!

I found there is a missing period after the journal name in the CSE.bst file uploaded here. I corrected it and here you are free to use:

https://github.com/ErbB4/LaTex-bib/blob/main/CSE-modified.bst