# Modify CSE.bst to stop sorting bib entries alphabetically

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib, bibliographystyle

This question is based on the posting [cse-citation style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/284982/cse-citation-style).

I have a journal style requirement that requires the use of the `natbib` citation management package, the `sort&compress` option, superscript-style citation call-outs, and the `CSE-modified` bib style.

So, I tried:

```
\usepackage[super,sort&compress]{natbib} 
\bibliographystyle{CSE-modified}
```

However, `CSE-modified` (or, for that matter, `CSE`) are set to sort the bibliographic entries in alphabetical order of authors' surnames. How can I modify either bst file so that the bib entries are typeset in the order they are first cited in the text?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the inclarity. What i mean is that I am unable to provide a sorted citation list in the CSE.bst format. It provides citations in the alphabetical author (lastname) format.

Comment: Right, I want the citation list in the order in which they appear in the text, but I am getting them to be alphabetical. I am wondering how to fix this problem, yet still have the CSE format. Is my question clear? So sorry again for the confusion.

Comment: thanks, done. feel free to make further helpful suggestions: i do hope that someone can help lead me to a solution of this problem.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your file some more to (hopefully) clarify its objective. I've also deleted my earlier comments as they are no longer of any relevance. (You may want to delete your comments as well...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you proceed as follows:

- Make a copy of the file `CSE-modified.bst` and name the copy, say, `CSE-nosort.bst`.
- Open the file `CSE-nosort.bst` in a text editor. The program you use to edit your tex files will do fine.
- Toward the very end of the file, locate the two lines that just contain one word: `SORT`. (In my copy of the file, these lines are numbered 1465 and 1531.)
- Comment out these two lines.
- Save the file `CSE-nosort.bst` in the directory that contains your main tex file(s). Alternatively, save the file in a directory that's searched by BibTeX and update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably. (If you don't know what the preceding sentence means, you should probably choose the first option...)
- In your main tex file, change the instruction

  ```
   \bibliographystyle{CSE-modified}
  ```

  to

  ```
   \bibliographystyle{CSE-nosort}
  ```

  and perform a full (re)compilation cycle: LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more.

---

A full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) and its output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

%% Create a sample bib file, with 8 dummy entries, "on the fly":
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{a,author="A",title="xx",year=3001}
@misc{c,author="C",title="zz",year=3003}
@misc{e,author="E",title="vv",year=3005}
@misc{f,author="F",title="uu",year=3006}
@misc{g,author="G",title="tt",year=3007}
@misc{h,author="H",title="ss",year=3008}
@misc{d,author="D",title="ww",year=3004}
@misc{b,author="B",title="yy",year=3002}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[super,sort&compress,square,comma]{natbib} 
\bibliographystyle{CSE-nosort}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\dots as shown in previous studies.\cite{g,e,d,c,a} % cite 5 of the 8 entries
\nocite{*} % make sure all 8 entries in the bib file are processed
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```