# custom text in reference list

Tags: biblatex, biber, zotero

I'm using Zotero to export my references to a `.bib` file.

Using biblatex and biber, is there a way to reproduce the kind of "custom" bibliography entry seen here:

[image: summarized in...]

This kind of reference list entry clearly doesn't conform to any obvious data structure, but is reasonably important in my field of study.

Comment: Perhaps these could help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/105447 ; https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6743/105447. Anyway, I think your question would clearly benefit if you stated explicitly the requirements you want/need, instead of just supplying an example of a single entry.

Comment: It would also help if you could give an idea of the styles you are using at the moment (an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) would make it easier for us to get started). A solution depends on the style you use. But I will admit that the output looks a bit non-standard, so we might have to get a bit hacky.

Comment: Interestingly, this almost matches `biblatex-sbl` (though given the field, you don't want to use this). But it's similar to `biblatex-chicago`. In `biblatex-sbl` I made a custom entry type called `conferencepaper`. The "summarized in" bit can be handled using a related entry. As @moewe has said, we need to know the biblatex style you are using before giving an answer.

Comment: It would also be good to know what this type of reference is meant to look like in the bibliography (if it's different from the note).

Comment: @DavidPurton The snippet I included *is* the bibliography. In the text you'd just get [18] or Rhomberg (1966), depending on your style.

Comment: @LondonRob Ah - my mistake. So what style are you currently using for all your other reference types? Just the default `biblatex` numeric style? Or something different/modified? a MWE with what you have so far would still be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really only to give you an idea of what is possible with `biblatex`. It will not give you the output you want for other reference types. But with this as a starting point and looking through the file `standard.bbx` and the `biblatex` manual, you should be able to set things up as you need.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dateabbrev=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@conferencepaper{rhomberg:1945,
  author = {Rhomberg, Richard R.},
  title = {A Short-term World Trade Model},
  eventtitle = {First World Congress of the Econometric Society},
  venue = {Rome},
  eventdate = {1945-09-09/1945-09-14},
  related = {rhomberg:related},
  relatedstring = {summarized}
}
@suppperiodical{rhomberg:related,
  journaltitle = {Econometrica},
  volume = {34},
  date = {1966},
  pages = {90-91}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\pagestyle{empty}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{conferencepaper}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{conf:event+venue+date}}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
\newbibmacro*{conf:event+venue+date}{%
  \printtext{Paper presented at the}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield{eventtitle}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{venue}%
  \newunit
  \printeventdate}
\DeclareFieldFormat[conferencepaper]{title}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1\adddot}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[suppperiodical]{volume}{#1}
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addcolon}
\renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\addspace}
% the following section ensures that punctuation is inside quotation
% marks and formats the date as in your example: Day, Month Year
% (though why you would want a comma after the Day is a complete mystery
% to me)
\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
  \uspunctuation
  \protected\def\mkdaterangecomp{%
    \mkdaterangetrunc{long}}%
  \protected\def\mkdaterangeterse{%
    \mkdaterangetrunc{short}}%
  \protected\def\mkdaterangecompextra{%
    \mkdaterangetruncextra{long}}%
  \protected\def\mkdaterangeterseextra{%
    \mkdaterangetruncextra{short}}%
  \protected\def\mkbibdatelong#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\thefield{#3}%
       \iffieldundef{#2}{}{\addcomma\nobreakspace}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}}%
    \iffieldbibstring{#1}
      {\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}
      {\dateeraprintpre{#1}\stripzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
}
\begin{document}
Filler text \autocite{rhomberg:1945}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Impressive stuff David. I think it's fair to say that "there's no easy way that doesn't require some serious coding knowledge'' would be a good summary of this answer too!