# Customizing Bibliography using biblatex

Tags: biblatex, macros, date

I'm struggling with understanding how to change the bibliography in biblatex. The style I'm using is "numeric-comp" which according to my MWE below gives me the following order:

Name, G., “Title of Article no. 1”, 2020 Journal of Something Great 5.1, pp. 21-42

But what I need is to move the date after the authors and also to set the chapter number bold and the journal in italics, so that it looks like:

Name, G., (2020) *Title of Article no. 1*, Journal of Something Great **(5)**, 21-42

According to [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6743/biblatex-changing-the-order-of-entries), I have changed the macro for "journal+issuetitle" but I can only move it a different place after the Journal. Could anyone please help me with what I'm missing? Here is the MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}{demobib.bib}
@ARTICLE{article1,
  author = {Name, Givenname},
  title = {Title of Article no. 1},
  journal = {Journal of Something Great},
  year = {2020},
  volume = {5},
  number = {1},
  pages = {21-42},
}

@ARTICLE{article2,
  author = {Name, Givenname},
  title = {Title of Article no. 2},
  journal = {Journal of Something Even Greater},
  year = {2021},
  volume = {4},
  number = {2},
  pages = {42-84},
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[english]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric-comp, giveninits=true, maxnames = 3, bibencoding=utf8, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}

\bibliography{demobib}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
 \usebibmacro{date}
\setunit{\addspace}
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
%  \setunit{\addspace}% DELETED
 %\setunit{\addcolon\space}% DELETED
%  \usebibmacro{issue}% DELETED
  \newunit}

\DeclareNameAlias{author}{last-first}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}


\begin{document}

\parencite{article1}

\parencite{article2}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
´´´
```

Comment: Welcome. // Does this long answer help https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13076 ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. that's a great answer helping me with every question except how to change dates in position. I have seen that style=authoryear may solve it, but it's not numeric anymore and I can't find any way to combine both (numeric citation style and bibliography with author, date, journal, volume, pages). Do you have any additional sources?

Comment: You can find so called "Related links" to the right of your question many times, like this one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6743/biblatex-changing-the-order-of-entries?noredirect=1&lq=1 . You can also use the search field on top, like: ** [biblatex] date order **, or: ** [biblatex] customizing **, where the first one is a valid tag. Click on the field to see valid syntax for search terms. // Also, I'm sure you'll have more replies here soon, either as comment or with an example.

Comment: Oh that's great! ```\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%´´´ was what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Comment: Fine :) // Once it works, please post yourself an answer showing the solution, best with screenshot and relevant code (i.e. ready to copy and compile for us). This way this community can still see your problem(=question) and a solution (=answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The classical trick to make your numeric bibliography look more author-year-y is shown in [Combining style numeric with style authoryear in BibLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/314014/35864).

For the "in:" I recommend one of the solutions from [Suppress "In:" biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10682/35864) (I picked the `biblatex-ext` solution).

In order to reformat the output of the `volume` and `pages` fields, you can use `\DeclareFieldFormat` (see amongst others [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864)). To get rid of `number` use a Biber sourcemap ([Disable ISSN but keep ISBN with biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40097/35864)).

```
\documentclass[english]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  citestyle=ext-numeric-comp,
  bibstyle=ext-authoryear,
  sorting=none,
  giveninits=true,
  maxnames = 3,
  articlein=false,
]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\input{ext-numeric.bbx}
\makeatother

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\DeclareNameAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{sortname}


\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\mkbibbold{\mkbibparens{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{pages}{#1}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps{
    \map{
      \pertype{article}
      \pertype{periodcial}
      \step[fieldset=number, null]
    }
  }
}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{sigfridsson,worman,geer}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson, E. and Ryde, U. (1998), “Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments”, Journal of Computational Chemistry (19), 377–395, doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]

Note that I switched from `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` to `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` in the MWE. The latter is already the default, so strictly speaking need not be included any more. UTF-8 is the de facto standard encoding nowadays and some of `biblatex`'s features work best with UTF-8 (instead of Latin1).